# Changing remote_host field in Logstash AccessEvent Fields to reflect X-Forward-For header - Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, amazon-elb, spring-logback, logstash-logback-encoder, remote-host

We are logging client access using Logtash, all logs are logging the load balancer I.P.
I was wondering if there is a way to configure logging client I.P's in the Logtash pattern using the "X-Forwarded-For HTTP header"? Best scenario would be changing the remote_host field. I was thinking of using AccessEventCompositeJsonEncoder to redefine each field but this may be an overkill.
Thank you for your help.